# Flex: Is there a way to tell when all code has stopped executing?

Tags: apache-flex

Whenever a user does something a a series of scripts are executing, after everything has finished and no more scripts are being run, and the app is essentially "idol" is there a way to capture that as an event?

Comment: Can you be more specific? Do you mean when there are no events taking place in Flex? Flex does not run scripts, do you mean calling Javascript externally and seeing when that finishes?

Comment: I do not mean JS, When I said scripts I was referring to AS3 code. I mean like when after all FLEX code has stopped running, for example, if you were to step through the code in debugger, the point after it reaches its final step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the simplest form, you should know that all "actions" are complete when you reach the end of your event listener.

For instance, if you create button with click handler like this:

```
<mx:Button id="clickMeButton" label="Click me" click="clickMeButton_clickHandler();" />
```

You would have this event listener function:

```
private function clickMeButton_clickHandler():void
{
    // process your logic

    // process more logic

    // process even more logic

    // the event listener logic is complete here (right before the closing bracket)
}
```

Comment: Actually this does make since...for some reason I was thinking that other functions that the event listener called could still be executing when the handler function ended, but now that I think about it, it always waits for each line to complete all tasks before it goes to the next line, even function calls, so ya at the end of the handler it should all be done. I guess it just didn't dawn on me until you said so. (well unless its something running at an interval or timer but I'm not interested in that anyways.) Thanks!